# Trying to get swift package example to work

Tags: swift3, swift-package-manager

I'm working through the first example in [swift-package-manager/Documentation/Usage.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#require-system-libraries)

My setup: macOS 10.12.1, Brew (`jpeg-8d` and `jasper-1.900.21`), Swift 3.0.1

The instructions don't mention that `example/Package.swift` needs this line or it won't build:  
    `name: "example",`
The errors are:

```
/Users/yost/p/swift/package-example/work/example/Package.swift:3:22: error: missing argument for parameter 'name' in call
let package = Package(
                     ^
PackageDescription.Package:18:12: note: 'init(name:pkgConfig:providers:targets:dependencies:exclude:)' declared here
    public init(name: String, pkgConfig: String? = default, providers: [PackageDescription.SystemPackageProvider]? = default, targets: [PackageDescription.Target] = default, dependencies: [PackageDescription.Package.Dependency] = default, exclude: [String] = default)
           ^
Can't parse Package.swift manifest file because it contains invalid format. Fix Package.swift file format and try again.
error: invalid manifest format
```

It's not in the instructions, but per the [Reference](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#package) section of this document, I added the line  
    `providers: [ .Brew("jpeg") ]`  
to `CJPEG/Package.swift` and tried to build without `jpeg` installed, and `swift build` didn't suggest running  
    `brew install jpeg`  
as it is supposed to. I did `brew install jpeg` and moved on.

Now with `jpeg` installed with brew, `swift build` got these errors:

```
Compile Swift Module 'example' (1 sources)
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h"
        ^
/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:755:3: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
  size_t free_in_buffer;        /* # of byte spaces remaining in buffer */
  ^
... blah blah ...
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/yost/p/swift/package-example/example/.build/debug.yaml
```

I found that I had to edit `/usr/local/include/jpeglib.h` to add  
    `#include <stdio.h>`  
at the top.

BTW, the `CJPEG/module.modulemap` file says:  
    `header "/usr/include/jpeglib.h"`  
The `jpeglib.h` file is in `/usr/local/include` and not in `/usr/include`. Why doesn't this cause a build error?

Anyway, at this point `swift build` got these build errors:

```
Compile Swift Module 'example' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/debug/example
ld: library not found for -ljpeg for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/yost/p/swift/package-example/example/.build/debug.yaml
```

I found that I can't just build with:  
    `swift build`  
I have to build with  
    `swift build -Xlinker -L/usr/local/include`

Those tweaks got me up through the `jpeglib` example.

When it came time to build the `JasPer` example, I get these errors:

```
Compile Swift Module 'example' (1 sources)
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/usr/local/include/jasper/jasper.h"
        ^
/usr/local/include/jasper/jasper.h:65:10: error: 'jasper/jas_config.h' file not found
#include <jasper/jas_config.h>
         ^
/Users/yost/p/swift/package-example/example/Sources/main.swift:3:8: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CJasPer'
import CJasPer
       ^
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /Users/yost/p/swift/package-example/example/.build/debug.yaml
```

Thanks to Vadim's answer, I now know I have to build with  
    `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib`

But I don't see yet what I can add to `Package.swift` so that I can build simply with  
    `swift build`

Answer (score 3):

SwiftPM updated the documentation with better explanation around system packages and a new example.

https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#require-system-libraries

Answer (score 0):

It is `-Xcc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib`.

Note that in order to use `swift build` without arguments, you can specify [`pkgConfig` property](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#pkgconfig) for your libraries, if they have `.pc` entries for [pkg-config utility](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html).

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you please be less brief? I don't understand any of this: "if they have .pc entries for pkg-config utility". What has pkg-config utility have to do with swift packages? Thanks

Comment: To clarify my answer: first you can just use `-Xcc -I/usr/local/include -Xlinker -L/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @silvalli second, if you want to use `swift build` without specifying the flags, you can use `pkgConfig` property for your libraries. It is described [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#pkgconfig):  _It defines the name of the pkg-config (.pc) file that should be searched and read to get the additional flags like include search path, linker search path, system libraries... etc._ However, not all system libraries have `.pc` entries. If they do, `pkgConfig` property will work, if not -  you will have to specify the flags with `swift build`

Answer (score 0):

The SwiftPM team expanded the [Swift Packages](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md) documentation and fixed a lot of problems (as Ankit Agarwal said).